# Elite Dangerous SRV without season pass

Tags: elite-dangerous, elite-dangerous-horizons

Is it possible to drive SRV without buying horizons season pass? I cant find SRV Hangar module.

Comment: If it's part of that DLC, and you don't have it, it makes sense that you can't find the module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No**. SRVs are a part of Horizons along with planetary landing modules. You cannot purchase SRV bays or SRVs without Horizons.

Comment: No SRV hangar modules without season pass is obvious if there are no planetary landings. When you come near planet you see parameters like you can land but you actually cant. That confused me.

Comment: @Enforcer those parameters have always been there.